# Implications of || in outer joins

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

the first code below brings the desired result but the second does not.
what are the implications of using the || operator?

**First query:**

```
SELECT
    a.ID_CUSTOMER,
    a.ID_VENDOR
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.ID_CUSTOMER=b.ID_CUSTOMER
AND a.ID_VENDOR=b.ID_VENDOR
WHERE 1=1
AND b.ID_CUSTOMER IS NULL
AND b.VENDOR IS NULL
```

**Second query:**

```
SELECT
    a.ID_CUSTOMER,
    a.ID_VENDOR
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.ID_CUSTOMER||a.ID_VENDOR=b.ID_CUSTOMER||b.ID_VENDOR
WHERE b.ID_CUSTOMER||b.ID_VENDOR IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` is string concatenation.  If *any* of the values are `NULL`, then the result is `NULL`, so it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE b.ID_CUSTOMER IS NULL OR b.ID_VENDOR IS NULL
```

In addition, the string concatenation has no "boundaries", so `'123'||'456'` matches `'12'||'3456'`.

Comment: Do I understand properly: if for instance 
````
a.ID_CUSTOMER is null
and b.ID_CUSTOMER is null
````
then no row will be selected in both cases even if ID_VENDOR is not null?

Comment: @Califfo . . . That is how `and` works.  Both conditions need to be true.